# Why won't Ubuntu show section 3 of signal manual?

Tags: command-line

The title says it all. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and I would like to read section 3 of the documentation of `signal`.

However, when I type the following the my terminal window:

```
$ man 3 signal
```

I get:

```
No manual entry for signal in section 3
```

However, I have found it somewhere else online. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *think* it's because - **in Linux** - `signal` is implemented as a *system call* rather than a *library function*, and therefore belongs in Section 2 of the manual rather than Section 3.

You can add a Section 3 man page for the POSIX `signal` implementation by installing the `manpages-posix-dev` package:

```
$ dpkg -S $(man -w 3 signal)
manpages-posix-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/signal.3posix.gz
```

For compatibility reasons, `glibc` also provides a `signal` library function that is documented in Section 3 of the manpages as `bsd_signal`:

```
BSD_SIGNAL(3)              Linux Programmer's Manual             BSD_SIGNAL(3)

NAME
       bsd_signal - signal handling with BSD semantics

SYNOPSIS
       #include <signal.h>

       typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

       sighandler_t bsd_signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between system call and library call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816791/what-is-the-difference-between-system-call-and-library-call)

Comment: There also a [`signal` in `3posix`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man3/signal.3posix.html) describing the POSIX spec

Comment: The `apropos` command can be used to find manual pages irrelevant of section.

Comment: @muru thanks - that seems more appropriate - I have updated the answer